# Text input inside multiple instances of a colour picker

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create multiple instances of a colour picker with a text input inside.

The commented code works for a single instance but I'm not sure how to use with it multiple instances. Here's my best effort..

https://jsfiddle.net/ogj5ynak/6/

```js
/*
 * Text input in multiple instance
*/
var target = document.querySelectorAll('.colorpicker');

var x = [];

for (var i = 0, len = target.length; i < len; i++) {

  var picker = new CP(target[i]);

  x[i] = document.createElement('input');
  x[i].type = 'text';

  var control = picker.picker.querySelector('.color-picker-control');
  control.appendChild(x[i]);

  x[i].oncut = pickerUpdate;
  x[i].oninput = pickerUpdate;
  x[i].onkeyup = pickerUpdate;
  x[i].onpaste = pickerUpdate;

  picker.on('change', function (color) {
    //x[i].value = '#' + color;
    this.target.value = '#' + color;
    this.target.style.backgroundColor = '#' + color;
  });

  function pickerUpdate () {
    picker.set(this.value);
    picker.picker.value = '#' + this.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://tovic.github.io/color-picker/color-picker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://recently.appifiny.io/content/script/lib.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="colorpicker">
<input type="text" class="colorpicker">
<input type="text" class="colorpicker">
<input type="text" class="colorpicker">
<input type="text" class="colorpicker">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the scope of `i` in the `change` event.

You can solve the problem saving the index:

```
picker.myprop = i;
```

And get the saved index:

```
picker.on('change', function (color) {

    var i = this.myprop; // HERE !

    x[i].value = '#' + color;
    this.target.value = '#' + color;

    this.target.style.backgroundColor = '#' + color;
    //app.settings[this.target.getAttribute('name')] = color;
});
```

[Try it on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ogj5ynak/9/)

Comment: Yes the issue was that i was undefined and I didn't know how to access the i in the change event. Awesome thanks :)

Comment: Oh, there is problem with the update method though, it is not possible to set a value in the inserted text input.

Comment: Ah, an array of pickers. Works great :)